# Magento URL translation "bug"?

Tags: magento, translation, store, analytics, sitemap.xml

We have sitemap.xml with URLs and google analytics started to throw errors like [this](http://alternativa-webshop.com/oils/cold-pressed-oils.html) not available, not found, etc...

We have English and Croatian store.
When you try to open (while on Croatian store) for example this [url](http://alternativa-webshop.com/oils/cold-pressed-oils.html)
it will be a 404 page.

Switch to English store: it works fine.

Anyone having idea what to do?

PS. Client don't want store code in URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long talk to client: 
URLs must stay the way they are. No suffixes no prefixes,
no subdomains, etc.

Checked other magento projects none of them have same behavior. :S
Most likely some of plugins is causing this.

I came up with simple solution but it didn't work.
Basicly idea was to check request via $_SERVER, check
URL and determinate which store to load inside of index.php

```
Mage::run($storeID);
```

but nothing happend...
Same problem again.
Here is another piece of code but I don't like it (it works but its stupid).:

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database",$link);


$path= substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)  ;// remove starting slash
$sql = "SELECT store_id  FROM  `core_url_rewrite` WHERE request_path = '{$path}'";
$rez= mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($sql,$link));
if(!empty($rez)){
    // found the url and storeID
    $store= $rez->store_id;
    if($store != Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()){ 
        // is store == current store?
        //Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
        if($store==1) $storeID="hr"; else $storeID="en";
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?___store=".$storeID;
        // Mage::run($storeID);   // doesn't work.
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        die; // just in case
    }   
}
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); //default exec
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 language websites are on the same domain name. This is causing problem.

You can :

use 1 subdomain per language
or
make the default language/store to english
or
make something more precise, like filtering user by origin (if you come from a search engine and you have an english url then go to english store).

etc.

Comment: hmmm subdomain sounds good! (face-palming myself atm, why didn't I remember that )

option 2: ummm the problem with users is irrelevant, main problem is google crawler).

Will go with 1st solution and post the result ;)
Thanks